# Remove C# attribute of a property dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I have a class with a set of properties As given below.

```
class ContactInfo
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Category("Contact Info")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [Category("Contact Info")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

The objects of this class is being assigned to a property grid, so that the users can **update an existing contact**. you can see that Mobile is marked as ReadOnly.

But, when I want to add an **entirely new Contact**, I would want the users to be able to edit the contact Mobile also. For that I need to **remove the Readonly property dynamically** from the Type, before assigning the object to the property grid. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not remove the attribute at runtime, but you can use reflection to change the ReadOnly attribute's ReadOnly private backing field to False. Making it the equivalent of [ReadOnly(false)]

See this article for details:

http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html

Edit: fixed link

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Comment: link is no longer valid

Comment: The article is available through the Waback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190907182632/http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree w/ Omu;  you're really talking about two classes (view models) in this case, to support your two different views.  Something like

CreateContactViewModel and EditContactViewModel

Answer (score 2):

The CodingLight.com blog moved to blogspot (the above link is broken).
See [http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907182632/http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html).

Moreover, SysAdmin's followup did not mention the `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]` attribute that seems to be necessary for an actually-working solution.

Finally, I believe that even David Morton (author of the quoted article) missed one very important thing: if the class (`ContactInfo`, in SysAdmin's followup example) does not have **at least** one property with the `[ReadOnly]` attribute defined at compile time, then when the "isReadOnly" FieldInfo is set to true at runtime the result is that **the whole class** turns read-only.

Comment: New link is also broken.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible at the moment to remove attributes dinamycally (at runtime)

as a suggestion you can do 2 classes: one with the attributes and one without

Comment: There's no need to make 2 classes, reflection can be used to modify the boolean field of the ReadOnly attribute and change it to false (not read only).

Answer (score 0):

I followed up the suggestion by Legenden. Here is what I came up with

```
class ContactInfo
{
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [Category("Contact Info")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        [Category("Contact Info")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public void SetMobileEdit(bool allowEdit)
        {
             PropertyDescriptor descriptor =  TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["Mobile"];

             ReadOnlyAttribute attrib = (ReadOnlyAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];

             FieldInfo isReadOnly = attrib.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

             isReadOnly.SetValue(attrib, !allowEdit);
        }
}
```

Comment: I think that while this works, it's not a good design.  The responsibilities are bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

And the original "link" show this:
[image]

Now the link won't break again