# How to add an attribute to a property at runtime

Tags: c#, attributes

```
//Get PropertyDescriptor object for the given property name
var propDesc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))[propName];

//Get FillAttributes methodinfo delegate
var methodInfo = propDesc.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsFamily || m.IsPublic && m.Name == "FillAttributes");

//Create Validation attribute
var attribute = new RequiredAttribute();
var  attributes= new ValidationAttribute[]{attribute};

//Invoke FillAttribute method
methodInfo.Invoke(propDesc, new object[] { attributes });
```

Hi I am trying to add Validation attribute at runtime using the above code. However I am getting the below exception:

> Collection was of a fixed size

Answer (score 240):

Don't let someone tell you that you can't do it. You can run for president if you want :-)

For your convenience, this is a fully working example

```cs
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomeAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Value = "Test";
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanAddAttribute()
{
    var type = typeof(SomeClass);

    var aName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("SomeNamespace");
    var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);
    var tb = mb.DefineType(type.Name + "Proxy", System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public, type);

    var attrCtorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
    var attrCtorInfo = typeof(SomeAttribute).GetConstructor(attrCtorParams);
    var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attrCtorInfo, new object[] { "Some Value" });
    tb.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);

    var newType = tb.CreateType();
    var instance = (SomeClass)Activator.CreateInstance(newType);

    Assert.AreEqual("Test", instance.Value);
    var attr = (SomeAttribute)instance.GetType()
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false)
        .SingleOrDefault();
    Assert.IsNotNull(attr);
    Assert.AreEqual(attr.Value, "Some Value");
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the motivational speak!

Comment: Hmm, seems we can't use this technique for enum members. I get an error saying the parent class is sealed...

Comment: @Jerther, the code creates a proxy class which inherits the base class at runtime. So yes, this does not work for sealed classes.

Comment: This adds an attribute to the class instead of a property of the class, right?

Comment: @Denny That's true but the concept will be the same. Property will have to be virtual for this to work and you will neeed to emit some IL code.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720275/98491) should help you out.

Comment: The code being a lill abstruse, in your example, what's being added to what now?

Comment: @JeromeJ The code dynamically creates a new class that inherits from `SomeClass` adds the `class level` attribute `SomeAttribute`, creates an instance and verifies the result. Just like you could do statically with  `[SomeAttribute("Some Value")] public class SomeClassProxy : SomeClass { }; var instance = new SomeClassProxy();`

Comment: A bit late here but the solution was quoted in another answer. So, instance variable is in fact an instance of a class which inherits from the original. And everything that uses reflection (and this is how custom attributes are used) will see no attributes applied to typeof(SomeClass) or instance.GetType(), right?

Comment: @AlexanderChristov Yes and no. While SomeClass isn't modified `instance.GetType()` will be `SomeClassProxy` and this will most likely work for code that takes a type or object as an argument for attribute querying. However, a hard coded `typeof(SomeClass).GetCustomAttributes(...)` won't work.

Comment: @Jurgen: Yes, in some case this might work, I do agree. However, this is a huge deviation from normal coding practices (shortest distance to target), this is why I would reconsider the need to dynamically inject an attribute. This is an excellent example of a suggestion to rethink and reformulate the problem - .NET is almost perfect in this respect.

Comment: @AlexanderChristov Obviously, you can't just change an existing class without recompiling. If you have a class `A` from an assembly that is out of your control and you have a method `B` out of your control that expects some attribute metadata, this is a working example. Proxy classes are quite common pattern, i.e. EntityFramework does this to implement lazy loading.

Comment: in .NET 6 this didn't work for me when I was trying to use reflection AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() - I got an assembly not found and apparently it's not supported in .NET Core - anyone got the same?

Comment: I just tested it with .NET core 6 on windows an linux and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` returns a result. Even more, the whole code runs fine (except `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly` has to be replaced with `System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly`. So no issue here.

Comment: Seems like the downvoted answer is actually the answer then. This is creating a new class, not taking the existing class and adding an attribute to a property.

Answer (score 10):

The top answer is awesome. Recently, a library has been developed, that abstracts away all of that complexity, and gives you something as simple as this:

```
var attributeType = typeof(CustomAAttribute);
var attributeParams = new object[] { "Jon Snow" };
var typeExtender = new TypeExtender("ClassA");
typeExtender.AddProperty("IsAdded", typeof(bool), attributeType, attributeParams);
```

To work with. details of how to install and use the library can be found [here](https://github.com/NdubuisiJr/TypeExtender)

Disclaimer: I developed this library and I've been using it for a lot of projects and it works like magic

Comment: but you can't add attribute to *Existing* property, can you ?

Comment: It depends on your use case. You can extend the class with TypeExtender, then add a property with the same name and signature (property hiding), and then attach the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Use [FastDeepCloner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/) which I developed.

```
public class test{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

var prop = DeepCloner.GetFastDeepClonerProperties(typeof(test)).First();
prop.Attributes.Add(new JsonIgnoreAttribute());
// now test and se if exist 
prop = DeepCloner.GetFastDeepClonerProperties(typeof(test)).First();
bool containAttr = prop.ContainAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>()
// or 
JsonIgnoreAttribute myAttr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>();
```

Comment: How would I do the deep clone and add an attribute to the class instead of the properties?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because the `FillAttributes` method expects a parameter of the IList type and you are passing an array. Below is the implementation of [MemberDescriptor.FillAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.fillattributes.aspx):

```
protected virtual void FillAttributes(IList attributeList) { 
    if (originalAttributes != null) {
        foreach (Attribute attr in originalAttributes) {
            attributeList.Add(attr);
        } 
    }
}
```

As you can see, `FillAttributes` just fills the `attributeList` parameter with all attributes of your property. And to make your code work, change the `var  attributes= new ValidationAttribute[]{attribute};` line with:

```
var attributes = new ArrayList { attribute };
```

This code has nothing with adding attributes to property of type at runtime. This is "adding attribute to the `PropertyDescriptor`" extracted from type and has no sense unless you are trying to build a type at runtime which is based on an already existing type.

Answer (score -14):

It is not possible to add Attributes in run-time. Attributes are static and cannot be added or removed.

Similar questions:

- [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)
- [Remove C# attribute of a property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483124/remove-c-sharp-attribute-of-a-property-dynamically)