# Dynamically add UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute to delegate

Tags: c#, attributes, runtime, marshalling

I have a CreateDelegate method, and I use

```
Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(func_addr, CreateDelegate())
```

It works very well, but now I need to Marshal as ThisCall.
So func_addr is a "CallingConvention.ThisCall". Statically, this is working :

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
delegate int d_Add(IntPtr _this, int x, int y);
...
var value = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<d_Add>(Addfunc_addr)(_this, 50, 100);
// return 150;
```

I would like to do add the UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute at runtime to my fresh delegate from CreateDelegate, or any way to marshal my delegate as ThisCall, is this possible ?

*I found this thread : [Add Custom Attribute at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-at-runtime) but in my case it is not a custom attribute.*