# serialize only one property of a class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a class which have about 20 members. I need to serialize my the object of this  class in a XML. But condition is I need only one member in the XML.

How can I do this.

**EDIT** : But at some time, I would like to serialize all the members. So I can't use [XMLIgnore] attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following attribute for all the members you don't want to serialize,

```
[XmlIgnore()]
public Type X
{
get;set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface and control the reading/writing of the fields yourself, based on some external parameter, i.e.

```
class CustomXml: IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        //
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (SerializationParameter.FullSerialization)
           //deserialize everything
        else
           //deserialize one field only
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (SerializationParameter.FullSerialization)
           //serialize everything
        else
           //serialize one field only
    }
}
```

where `SerializationParameter.FullSerialization` is an example of how you could control what is serialized when.

Answer (score 1):

you can put [XmlIgnore] attribute on all members you do not want to be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to make properties non-serializable in.NET using attributes.

You may set attributes `[NonSerialized]` or `[XmlIgnore]`

If you serializing in binary or SOAP you should use `[NonSerialized]`, if you want to serialize just in XML you should use `[XmlIgnore]`.

So in your case the answer is `[XmlIgnore]`

EDIT:
There is no way to apply attributes to properties dynamically.
Here some info about that here: [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c) and here [Remove C# attribute of a property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483124/remove-c-attribute-of-a-property-dynamically)

Also as a workout you may have different copies of your class with different attributes.

OR

Have a copy of your class set all props as serializable but populate only properties you need, this way every thing else will be null/empty and after serialization of that class you should get the XML you need.

Answer (score 0):

mark the other attributes

```
<NonSerializable()> _
Property someproperty
```

End Property