# Range validation - make exceptions to the rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class with a property which has a range attribution on it.

```
        [Required]
        [Range(5, 9999)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
```

Which is respected at all times and on any user input.

But on one specific code path, where i am automating some entries, i want to be able to set the Price to 0. So i want to programmatically tell this model class to ignore this requirement.

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Are you supposed to be using double for what appears to be a monetary value?

Comment: Good question ... what do you usually use? in sql server and .net?

Comment: Decimal http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367287/asp-net-mvc-3-disable-required-validation-attribute-under-certain-circumstances), but maybe I'm not completely understanding your requirements.

For your scenario I might try implementing the IValidatableObject interface so that way you can control the validation logic rather than using a declarative validation pattern.

Comment: i am not using views in many cases. Some times these models are called using API's or windows services etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a derived type of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`. The implementation can be similar to RangeAttribute class with additional parameter of exceptional values.

Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx) for details on how to do this.