# Remove client-side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Assuming I have a specific problem which I need to remove some dataannotations's required attributes, how can I do this?

I know about view-model but I don't want to use it for some reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to disable validation for a single field in client side then you can override the validation attributes as follows:

```
@Html.TexBoxFor(model => model.SomeValue,                  
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false }})
```

Here is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367287/asp-net-mvc-3-disable-required-validation-attribute-under-certain-circumstances) for more answers

Comment: your can use `@Html.TexBoxFor(model => model.SomeValue,                  
new {data_val = false})` and the compiler is smart enough to convert the '_' to '-'

Answer (score 1):

this will disable the validations on certain elements based on a selector

```
var validationSettings = $.data($('#formToValidateId').get(0), 'validator').settings;  
validationSettings.ignore = '.ignore';
```

check this [blog](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/03/aspnet-mvc-3-configuring-unobtrusive.html) for more info