# Field is required in specific form ASP MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working in ASP .NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to validate a field as required in a specific form, but in the database the field is not required. Is it possible to do this with ValidationMessageFor or will do I have to do in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Required` attribute from your model

Comment: In model it is not required, but in specific form i want it do

Comment: check it using javascript..whether value is null or not before submitting

Comment: I thought so, but could be any way to do so and easier

Comment: i think...javascript would be easier to do

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are employing just one model for view and for business domain/data access as well. I assume your application is small enough to live up with this.

When it becomes larger enough, more impedance mismatch could come up. It is recommended then to separate your model at least for views and business domain/data access. There are good tools to automate obvious conversions like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

**Updated (as it both relates to view models):**

The problem is [known](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367287/3170952) and has several approaches, from which I prefer most [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781066/3170952):

```
@Html.TexBoxFor(model => model.YourField, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-val", false }})
```

as it employs ASP.NET MVC helpers and you are free from maintaining additional js code

Comment: I'm just using the same entity to different forms. And there is a specific form that a certain field is required. I've done the validations in javascript, thanks anyway