# Can I remove the validation of specific property of model in specific actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to **remove the validation of a specific property** in ***ASP.NET Core*** Model for a specific action only like edit.

For Ex:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public Guid User_ID { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string User_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }        

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Mobile_No { get; set; }
}
```

Here in the above template of the model, I want to remove the validation for the password property in **Edit action** because i don't want to update that in the particular action.

Comment: Were my edits OK? I see you rolled them back and then forward again.

Comment: Hey, here my question is different and particularly the question you have duplicated is for different technology. I have given the right and short answer for the question. So, Please understand my topic for the question.

Comment: A duplicate just means that the answer to your question is available elsewhere. I believe the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29539943/2630078) from that question is _exactly_ the code you've shown in your answer. Duplicates aren't _bad_; in this case, the duplicate also suggests other options that are valid in both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Finally i got the answer after trying my efforts.

For ex:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id,Users users)
    {
        if (id != users.User_ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ModelState.Remove("Password");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ...
```

There is a method remove in ModelState that we can use to remove a specific validation as we needed for specific key.

**ModelState.Remove("Password");**

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary.remove?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Please look at this approach described by [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367788/3590235) which might work better for you.