# Validation based on attribute

Tags: asp.net-core

```
[Required]
public string? Description { get; set; }
```

I am using    `<DataAnnotationsValidator />`

I have the above property in a class and validating the model. Sometimes depending on some condition the Description field may not be a required field, how to remove the validation in that case?

Is it a way to programmatically remove the required attribute depending on the conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Required validation attribute under certain circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367287/disable-required-validation-attribute-under-certain-circumstances)

Comment: That one answers the MVC. This one is regarding the blazor

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. You could try use [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/blazor.html) for Blazor and then create a validator for your model using [conditional validation rules](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html).