# How to set/remove attributes dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attributes

I am using from attribute validation in my project.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "DepartmentCode is Required")]
public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
```

In some case DepartmentCode isn't required. How can I dynamically ignore Validation in my case?

Comment: If it is not required in some cases, why do you set an attribute? Attributes are static, why not create a property or something like that?

Comment: In your code it might be called *departmant*, but your error message should definitely call it *department*.

Comment: @ H.B. In fact my business changed in one case ....In another case this property is required...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: [Remove C# attribute of a property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483124/remove-c-sharp-attribute-of-a-property-dynamically)

Anyway I think the proper solution is to inherit an attribute from `RequiredAttribute` and override the `Validate()` method (so you can check when that field is required or not). You may check `CompareAttribute` implementation if you want to keep client side validation working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dynamically adding and removing validation, you would be better served to create an attribute that better serves this purpose.

The following article demonstrates this (MVC3 with client-side validation too):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the RequiredAttribute from your model and check it once you've hit your controller and check it against whatever causes it to not be required.

If it falls into a case where it is required and the value is not filled in, add the error to the ModelState manually

`ModelState.AddModelError("DepartmantCode", "DepartmantCode is Required");`

You would just lose the validation on the client side this way

Answer (score 0):

I've got round this issue in the model, in some cases it's not ideal but it's the cheapest and quickest way.

```
public string NonMandatoryDepartmentCode
{
    get
    {
        return DepartmentCode;
    }
    set
    {
        DepartmentCode = value;
    }
}
```

I used this approach for MVC when a base model I inherited contained attributes I wanted to override.