# Adding or eliminating attribute at run time

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a class with a bunch of properties. Now I am going to add or eliminate some attributes to these properties at run time but i don't know how exactly i should do it.

**The Class**

```
Class myClass
{
    //Other codes
    public string DetailedAccountTitle
    {
        get { return detailedAccountTitle; }
        set { detailedAccountTitle = value; }
    }
    //Other codes
}
```

**Inside the caller**

```
if ((bool)e.Value)
{
    //Add the attribute
}
else
{
    //Eliminate it
}
```

Now as you can see I am controlling an event inside the caller and i hope it adds the attribute if it gets true and eliminate it if it does not.

Comment: Have you tried any code sample for this?

Comment: Side note: you can write it as `public string DetailedAccountTitle  { get; set; }`

Comment: @guy I know  that . tnx anyway : )

Comment: Are you looking into something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483124/remove-c-sharp-attribute-of-a-property-dynamically?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663763/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-property-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly when you want to use attribute value set value when needed and when don't simply set to empty or null

```
myClass myclass = new myClass();

if ((bool)e.Value)
{
    myclass.DetailedAccountTitle = "Set Value";
}
else
{
    myclass.DetailedAccountTitle = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: you did not get the question at all . first read this : [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)